# Is there a way to recover directory from (low power?) disconnected drives?

Tags: mac, usb, shell, power

Let me first describe the issue.  I work on a Macbook Air and have a pendrive permanently connected for largish work data.  About once a week it happens to me that power gets low - after I connect power I get the message that USB was disconnected incorrectly.  The usual situation is working on train for two hours, close the macbook to go to office, log in at office - or the other way - so solutions to keep power connected are not that useful.

And no I didn't remove it by accident - it's one of these drives that nearly don't stick out of the case where you almost need a tool to remove it.  After logging in the drive is again mounted at the same folder.  More annoying is in terminal wherever I am in a folder on this drive I get following error:

```
        shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
<E> fish: getcwd() failed with errno 2/No such file or directory
```

As you see I currently use fish - but using bash I have similar problems (though the error not at hand).

In shells I can get rid of it going to a folder on a different device and changing back. The name of the folder is exactly the same as before. The annoying thing is I like to have quite a number of session inside tmux and most run some processes (R and vim) - R can't recover by doing this, and in vim there is a mess of "files gone away" or "changed".  Both I am not able to fully recover and have to quit them as the errors never seem to stop. Obviously I lose unsaved data doing this and it takes some time till everything is set up again.  Interestingly gui apps handle this well and recover.

So is there a way to keep or recover the situation?

As layman I have the impression that there may be an issue waking up - that the processes come up to quick try to access the drive before it has come up from sleep.  Maybe I could just keep them asleep a little longer...

Comment: Stop the drive from loosing power - maybe use a USB hub connected to the wall ?

Comment: @davidgo theoretically this might work - but practically if I had power I could also plug in the notebook.

Comment: I misunderstood your usage case - I'm not a Mac user, but this sounds to me like an adjustment which needs to be made to power management to stop the USB drive from powering down.